# running ARM program on xcode

Tags: xcode, gcc

I'd like to have a compiler for ARM on my Mac, and I read somewhere that there is a way to run and maybe debug ARM code on Xcode.
Anyone has any hint on how I should do or if it is even possible?
Any other solution for ARM on Mac?
Thanks

Comment: Please complete your question by specifying what kind of ARM do you need - if it is about Cortex or similar, aka embedded - there are possible some other solutions than that in the response below. See for example this: http://embedxcode.weebly.com.

Answer (score 1):

## Running ARM code on macOS

See [How to emulate an ARM architecture under OSX 10.6 (“Snow Leopard”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535111/how-to-emulate-an-arm-architecture-under-osx-10-6-snow-leopard#9502382) The answers to this question include suggestions for:

### QEMU

> [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org) is a generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer.

QEMU can be installed from Homebrew: `brew install qemu`

### Skyeye

> [Skyeye](http://skyeye.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/SkyEye_User_Manual()) is a multi-architecture, multi-core, and highly scalable hardware simulation platform. Cur- rently it is implemented by the core library libcommon.so and a series of plug-ins based on the composition of the core library. SkyEye supports the system structure of ARM, Blackfin, Coldfire, PowerPC, MIPS, SPARC and x86.

Skyeye may be no longer under active development.

## Cross Compiling ARM with Xcode

Getting Xcode to correctly cross-compile non-iOS device ARM code on the Mac appears to be possible, if tricky. You may find focusing on command line compiling easier.

### embedXcode

> [embedXcode](http://embedxcode.weebly.com) is a template for Xcode, Apple's official IDE on Mac, and eases development for the [most popular embedded computing boards](http://embedxcode.weebly.com/supported-boards-and-ides.html).

[image: embedXcode grid of supported hardware]

### Alternative Approaches

- [Cross compiling ARM static lib with GCC for Mac iOS xCode projects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242847/)
- [Add a custom compiler to XCode 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941494/)

Comment: not a fare procedure, at least you can specify the source...

Comment: @yoan Which source are you referring to?

Comment: @yoan, I mentioned you in the edit comments to this question; see the answer's [edit history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/303560/revisions). You always have the ability to edit this answer or add your own answer.